# Meta-analysis on percentage of total calorie intake

Tags: meta-analysis, proportion, percentage, precision

We are looking at a number of studies which have profiled nutrient information which contributes to total daily calorie intake. For example, fibre might make up 5% of daily total calorie intake.

My question is whether it would be feasible to conduct a meta-analysis of proportions using this data? I am familiar with proportion/percentage meta-analysis, where the proportion/percentage is made up of number of observations of interest and number of total observations.

However here the equivalent to number of total observations is always going to be 100%, because the outcome is always the % of fibre out of 100% of calories.  How would I take into account the precision of the estimates based on the sample size? Is this possible?